# Encode unc path for firefox in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, firefox, encoding, character-encoding

I need to encode a path so firefox can open it directly. I've tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode, HttpUtility.HttpEncode and HttpUtility.HtmlEncode but none of these seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've managed to bypass the security aspect of this, right? How do you open local files directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpServerUtility.UrlPathEncode was the answer...